# 500 Internal Server Error on combining two functions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, server

I have two `POST` APIs :

```
def add_friend
   //do something
end
```

and

```
def delete_friend
   //do something
end
```

Both these APIs work correctly on POST requests. But when I combine these two functions and write one function which does both the jobs based on a POST request parameter, it gives `500 Internal Server Error`.

What is wrong?

Comment: What's the error in `development.log`?

Comment: You need to provide much more information: Parameters given, the stack trace, part of the methods...

Comment: Got it resolved. Error was due to some other reason.